# echo hello && $(echo "world") fails with "bash: world: command not found"

Tags: bash, command-substitution

the full command is `% echo hello && $(echo "world")`, where `%` is the shell prompt.

why does this fail?

I've noticed that the error is the same as if I had run the command substitution directly on bash as

`% $(echo "world")`

Answer (score 0):

It's trying to run the command 'hello', and failing, because that binary doesn't exist on your system.

An argument for echo should be in quotes, ie:

```
echo "hello"
```

Comment: I miscommunicated. the first hello IS printed, but the second, inside the command substitution, fails. I miswrote the question, let me update it.

Comment: also, though I appreciate your help, your answer is not actually accurate. The double quotes in echo are optional in this case. If you run the updated command, you'll find that the issue is not with the top hello outside of quotes, but with the inner world INSIDE double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

The grouping is wrong.

to group commands inside bash, use curly brackets like this:

`% echo hello && { echo "world"; }`

some notes on the syntax:

- the beginning curly bracket must be separated from the `echo`, or it will be taken to be part of the name of the command, called `{echo`.
- the command sequence inside the brackets must end with a semicolon `;`.

refer to section "3. Grouping Statements" of this page on control operations: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals#Control_Operators_.28.26.26_and_.7C.7C.29

Comment: Your 3rd bullet is wrong; `;}` is fine and not an error -- but if the `{` was previously wrong, then the error may be _reported_ on the `}`

Comment: oh, I see, thanks! I'll edit to reflect this